# Biased std, mstd in dolphindb which are similar to std(ddof=1 or 0) in pandas or numpy

Tags: window, dolphindb

Biased std, mstd in dolphindb which are similar to std(ddof=1 or 0) in pandas or numpy

The function std and mstd are used to caculate the standard deviation and the standard deviation in a sliding window. I want to ask is there a parament such like the ddof=1 or 0 in pandas and numpy to caculate the biased standard deviation?

Answer (score 0):

The [std](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/s/std.html) function can calculate the standard deviation, and the biased standard deviation can be calculated by the function 'stdp'.

The [mstd](https://www.dolphindb.com/help/FunctionsandCommands/FunctionReferences/m/mstd.html) function can calculate the moving standard deviation in a sliding window with a length of window. The deviation standard deviation can be calculated by the function 'mstdp'.